# Finding poles of function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose you have have the function $f(z) = (1+0.4z)/(1 - z^{3}/1.01^{3})$ . I want to find the poles of the function and sketch the spectral density. The answer states that the poles are at $1.01$, $1.01e^{2i\pi/3}$, and $1.01e^{-2i\pi/3}$.. I know the root is at -2.5.

Comment: The three points you gave are not poles... Your function is holomorphic, and it has no poles.

Comment: I made an edit. The poles are the roots of the denominator and the zeros are the roots of the numerator

Answer (score 1):

We essentially want to solve $\left(\dfrac z{1.01}\right)^3 = 1$.

Passing to [polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_form) $z = re^{i\theta}$, this turns into:

$$\left(\frac{r}{1.01}\right)^3e^{3i\theta} = 1$$

Equating the absolute values, we need $r$ to be $1.01$ because it is a real number. Now we're essentially left with:

$$e^{3i\theta} = e^0$$

By e.g. [Euler's Formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula), we obtain that:

$$3\theta \equiv 0 \pmod{2\pi}$$

There are essentially three solutions to this equation, $\theta = 0, \dfrac{2\pi}3, \dfrac{4\pi}3$. Since $\dfrac{4\pi}3 \equiv -\dfrac{2\pi}3 \pmod{2\pi}$, we obtain the given solutions for $z$.

Comment: I don't understand the part about equating the absolute values and r being 1.01. Is it possible you could expand on this part?

Comment: Since $|e^{3i\theta}| = 1$, the absolute value of the LHS is $(r/1.01)^3$; that of the RHS is manifestly $1$. Solving this (now real) equation gives $r = 1.01$.

Answer (score 0):

Three numbers which are claimed to be poles are not poles, they are zeros, actually the three cubic root of $1.01^3$ in the complex plane. The real one is $1.01$, the other ones are obtained by rotating the real root by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ (or $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ clock-wise)